# Saving Django ModelForms

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am using the modelForms to have a user/ a staff apply for leave but am unable to save the form into the db using the code below. My form submits validates and submits just fine but when i check on the admin site there are no new entries

Views.py:

```
@login_required
def ApplyLeave(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ApplyLeaveForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            leave = form.save(commit=False)
            messages.success(request, f'Submitted successfully')

            leave.staff = request.user.username
            leave.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = ApplyLeaveForm(instance=request.user)

    context = {'form': form,
              }

    return render(request, 'apply-leave.html', context)
```

forms.py:

```
class ApplyLeaveForm(LeaveForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = Leave
        fields = [
            'leave_type',
            'start',
            'end',
            'reason',
        ]
    start = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y'),
        input_formats=('%d/%m/%Y', )
        )
    end = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y'),
        input_formats=('%d/%m/%Y', )
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        if self.request:
            try:
                self.request.user.staffprofile
            except StaffProfile.DoesNotExist:
                pass
        else:
            self.fields['staff'].queryset = StaffProfile.objects.filter(
                id=self.request.user.staffprofile.id)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = True
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.render_required_fields = True
        self.helper.form_show_labels = True
        self.helper.html5_required = True
        self.helper.form_id = 'leave-application-form'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('staff', type="hidden"),
            Field('leave_type',),
            Field('start',),
            Field('end',),
            Field('reason',),
            FormActions(
                Submit('submitBtn', _('Submit'), css_class='btn-primary'),
            )
        )
```

Comment: Unable, how? What happens, what doesn't happen?

Comment: Please show ApplyLeaveForm Class in your Question

Comment: The view is looking fine. Need to see the ApplyLeaveForm class and the model.

Comment: I have added the code for the form, thanks

Comment: Why are you doing `instance=request.user`?  If it is a ModelForm where `model=Leave` then it doesn't make any sense to do `instance=request.user` because request.user isn't an instance of Leave.

Comment: @FiddleStix thanks i corrected that part and set the user this way and it worked            
 form.instance.staff = request.user.staffprofile then leave = form.save()